# jQuery import not functioning correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to import jQuery into an HTML project but when I open the page the jQuery function I have written doesn't occur when called.  I've verified the validity of the function and also tried it with some extremely basic jQuery functions.  I figure this must be a problem with the import but my research tells me I'm doing it correctly.  Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

qualdex=0;

function appendRow() {
    $('#Requirements').append("<td><select id=\"Id\" onChange=\"changeTextBox();\"><option value=\"\" selected>-- select an ID --</option></select></td>");
}

//Some javascript code
</script>
```

I've played around with moving the src statement and adding/removing the text/javascript tag but it still appears that jQuery hasn't been added to the project.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your page isn't run on a server, in that case add in the protocol in the jquery src.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the script to local directory, and link to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation for jQuery being unavailable is that you aren't accessing your page of HTTP or HTTPS, but are loading from a local file.

The scheme relative URI won't resolve to a jQuery resource on your hard disk.

Do your development work on a local web server, and access it via `http://localhost`.